# Sockets and Streaming in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, akka-stream, akka-http, playframework-2.6

I am reading the Play-Socket.io [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/play-socket.io/blob/master/docs/ScalaSocketIO.md#building-a-socketio-engine) and Play WebSocket [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-Akka-Streams-and-actors) on how to use them via Akka Streams.

I cannot understand why it's necessary to use `Flow.fromSinkAndSource`.

The documentation for Play WebSockets says:

> Note that while conceptually, a flow is often viewed as something that
>   receives messages, does some processing to them, and then produces the
>   processed messages - there is no reason why this has to be the case,
>   the input of the flow may be completely disconnected from the output
>   of the flow. Akka streams provides a constructor,
>   Flow.fromSinkAndSource, exactly for this purpose, and often when
>   handling WebSockets, the input and output will not be connected at
>   all.

I don't get this at all, why they should be disconnected at all? Why doesn't a simple `Flow` make sense here?

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot understand why it's necessary to use `Flow.fromSinkAndSource`....I don't get this at all, why they should be disconnected at all? Why doesn't a simple `Flow` make sense here?

In Play, a WebSocket message handler is a `Flow[In, Out, _]` (which is converted to/from a [`Flow[Message, Message, Any]`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.0-RC2/server-side/websocket-support.html#handling-messages) via a [`MessageFlowTransformer`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.WebSocket$$MessageFlowTransformer)). If you're using WebSockets in a request-response fashion, then you could use `Flow[In].map` or something with similar semantics, to implement this handler (the following examples are from the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-Akka-Streams-and-actors)):

```
def socket =  WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>

  // log the message to stdout and send response back to client
  Flow[String].map { msg =>
    println(msg)
    "I received your message: " + msg
  } // Flow[String, String, _]
}
```

In the above example, the input and output are connected: the input is transformed, and the result of that transformation is used as the output.

WebSockets may also be truly bidirectional, meaning that the input and output do not necessarily have to be connected. This is when `Flow.fromSinkAndSource` comes into play: the `Sink` and `Source` that are passed into this method are independent. A trivial example of this is a handler that ignores an incoming connection and simply sends a single message to the socket:

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>

  // Just ignore the input
  val in = Sink.ignore

  // Send a single 'Hello!' message and close
  val out = Source.single("Hello!")

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out) // Flow[String, String, _]
}
```

In the above example, `Flow.fromSinkAndSource` is used because the input and output are not connected: the input has nothing to do with the output.

Whether you use WebSockets in a request-response or a truly bidirectional manner, both approaches are modeled as a `Flow[In, Out, _]`. If you're using WebSockets in a truly bidirectional way, then you can use `Flow.fromSinkAndSource` to implement a `Flow[In, Out, _]`.

Comment: Thanks, My first question is why `in` is a type of Sink not source in the second example?
And if we are doing bi-directional communication, can I create 2 different `socket` instance like the second example that one just receive and consume and the other just send stuff? Are they going the same socket? Would appreciate if you can add these to the answer.

Comment: One other addition, I am thinking how would the answer looks like in a scenario that you have a request/response type of a communication but sometimes you want to push something to the client (e.g signed them out, notification), are we going to use 2 sockets? how can one reuse the same socket for that?